# TraMineR: Can I get the complete sequence if I give an event sub sequence?

Tags: r, traminer

I have a sequence dataset like below:

```
customerid    flag  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
abc234          1   3   4   3   4   5   8   4   3   3   2   14  14
abc233          0   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
qpr81           0   9   8   7   8   8   7   8   8   7   8   8   7
qnr94           0   14  14  14  2   14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14
```

Values in column `0` to `11` are the sequences. There are two sets of customers with flag=1 and flag=0, I have differentiating event sequences for both sets. ( Only frequencies and residuals for 2 groups are shown here)

```
Subsequence Freq.0      Freq.1     Resid.0       Resid.1
(3>4)       0.19208177  0.0753386   5.540793    -21.43304
(4>5)       0.15752553  0.059960497 5.115241    -19.78691
(5>4)       0.15950556  0.062782167 5.037413    -19.48586
```

I want to find the customer ids and the flags for which the event sequences match.

Should I write a python script to traverse the transactions or is there some direct method in R to do this?

`

```
CODE
--------------

library(TraMineR)

custid=c(a1,a2,a3,b4,b5,c6,c7,d8,d9)#sample customer ids
flag=c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)#flag
col1=c(14,14,14,14,14,5,14,14,2)
col2=c(14,14,3,14,3,14,6,3,3)
col3=c(14,2,2,14,2,14,2,2,2)
col4=c(14,2,2,14,2,14,2,2,14)
df=data.frame(custid,flag,col1,col2,col3,col4)#dataframe generation
print(df)
#Defining sequence from col1 to col4
df.s<-seqdef(df,3:6)
print(df.s)
#finding the transitions
transition<-seqetm(df.s,method='transition')
print(transition)
#converting to TSE format
df.tse=seqformat(df.s,from='SPS',to='TSE',tevent = transition)
print(df.tse)
#Event sequence generation
df.seqe=seqecreate(id=df.tse$id,timestamp=df.tse$time,event=df.tse$event)
print(df.seqe)
#subsequences
fsubseq <- seqefsub(df.seqe, pMinSupport = 0.01)
print(fsubseq)
groups <- factor(df$flag>0,labels=c(1,0))
#finding differentiating event sequences based on flag using ChiSquare test
diff <- seqecmpgroup(fsubseq, group = df$flag, method = "chisq")

#Using seqeapplysub for finding the presence of subsequences?
presence=seqeapplysub(fsubseq,method="presence")
print(presence[1:3,3:1])
```

`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you have state sequences and have transformed them into event sequences using the `seqecreate` function of `TraMineR`. The events you are considering are the state changes. Thus `(3>4)` stands for a subsequence with only one event, namely the event `3>4` (switching from 3 to 4). Then, you identify the event subsequences that best discriminate your two flags using the `seqefsub` and `seqecmpgroup` functions.

If this is correct, then you can identify the sequences containing each subsequence with the `seqeapplysub` function. I cannot illustrate here because you do not provide any code in your question. Look at the online help of the `seqeapplysub` function.

======= update referring to your added code =======

Here is how you get the ids of the sequences that contain the most discriminating subsequence.

First we extract the first three most discriminating sequences from your `diff` object. Second, we compute the `presence` matrix that provides a column for each extracted subsequence with a 1 in regard of the sequences that contain the subsequence and 0 otherwise.

```
diffseq <- seqefsub(df.seqe, strsubseq = paste(diff$subseq[1:3]))
(presence=seqeapplysub(diffseq, method="presence"))
```

Now you get the ids for the first subsequence with

```
custid[presence[,1]==1]
```

For the second it would be `custid[presence[,2]==1]` etc.

Likewise you get the flag with

```
flag[presence[,1]==1]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Gilbert! I looked at `seqeapplysub` function. For me, getting the customer id and flag is more important. I am looking at the `index` field  given by `seqecmpgroup` method. Have added the code, btw.